# How much would it cost to buy one of every retail LEGO set released in a year?

Tags: shopping, set-database

I'm curious: has anyone done the math to determine how much it would cost to purchase one of every retail Lego set released each year?

Clarifications:

- I don't know if there are sets available in the United States that aren't available in Europe (or vice versa).  Assume United States with USD prices.
- I'm asking about sets newly released that year, not sets from previous years that are still being sold.
- Obviously each year will be different.  Perhaps consider just 2016 and 2015 (and maybe a sampling of others to see what the trend is like).

Comment: Before doing anything else, I would send JANGBRiCKS on youtube a private message and see if he'll respond. He buys just about every set released by TLG to review them (out-of-pocket, too, not sponsored). He might have a good estimate to give you. [Here is Jang's Channel](https://www.youtube.com/user/LEGOJANG)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

[Brickset](http://brickset.com/sets/) allows you to export a search as .CSV and appears to include prices for all regularly available sets - this does exclude promotional sets (i.e. in-store, newspaper vouchers, magazine gifts, partner stores, or VIP/special offers) and educational sets (only available through specialist educational retailers), or pick-a-brick/model options.

[image: Export as CSV]

Running a quick SUM() over the price columns results in the following totals for 2015 and 2016 as examples - which gives you to total for the sets that were released in those teritories - if you want you can play around with the data yourself to merge the different sets, as well as apply either an average or premium amount (based on the number of bricks) for the promotional sets:

```
| Year | # Sets |    UK £   |    US $   |   CAN $   |   EUR €   |
|------|--------|-----------|-----------|-----------|-----------|
| 2015 |    771 | 12,607.44 | 16,117.06 | 18,364.45 | 14,140.92 |
| 2016 |    828 | 13,531.21 | 16,915.18 | 19,718.39 | 15,886.59 |
```

As you can see the total number of sets is variable (2011 had only 584 sets for example) so the total price will vary each year.

Comment: Very nice! (In case anyone else was wondering, those sums don't necessarily mean that collecting Lego is significantly cheaper in Canada with current exchange rates; apparently some sets aren't available there or there's just missing data.) It also includes a number of things that I didn't mean to include in my question (e.g. video games, stationery).  I will have to spend some time playing around with this. =)